# Magento 2: How to create new section for uploading multiple images for product

Tags: magento2

I am working on a Magento 2 project where there is a requirement for using different product images apart from existing product media images for 360 view of the product on details page so for that I need to create new tab in while adding new product just like "Images and video". Some have any idea how to do that in magento 2?

Comment: you can try [magento 2 360 product view](https://www.mageants.com/360-product-images-extension-for-magento-2.html) module hopefully it will resolve your issues